# How can I access the privileges list on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, privileges

I used to click on the point amount to access the [privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges) list, now clicking on it leads me to the reputation page. Is there any link on the site which I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on the arrow next to your username at the top of the page, or hover over your username. Once the popup appears, click the "privileges" link.

Comment: So, @O.D, it is "hidden" at http://stackoverflow.com/privileges ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Site design has changed since this question was asked in 2011.  The current location is in the achievements drop-down:

[image: screenshot]